# Filtering a sequence of options and collecting the values of all the Somes. Is there a built-in function in F# for that?

Tags: .net, f#

A common pattern in F# is to want to filter something by whether it is "Some"thing and in case it is, getting its value:

```
module Option =
    let values s =
        s
        |> Seq.filter Option.isSome
        |> Seq.map Option.get
```

I have the idea I've seen something like that in the F# libraries some time ago but I can't find them at the moment. Is there something like this function or will I have to use my hand-rolled one?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `Seq.choose`

```
s |> Seq.choose id
```

Here we use `id` as the input is the same as the output